# Differential equations: $(1+y)^2 = (1+x)^2 \frac{dy}{dx}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the differential equation:
>   $$(1+y)^2 = (1+x)^2 \frac{dy}{dx}$$

I don't know how to go about this?

But let me try:
$$(1+y)^2 dx=(1+y)^2 dy$$
$$\frac{dx}{(1+x)^2} =\frac{dy}{(1+y)^2}$$
Integrating both sides gives:
$$\arctan x=\int \frac{dy}{(1+y)^2}$$

Comment: Where did you see the derivative of $\tan^{-1}(x)$ in the DE ?

Comment: That's a standard integral for

Comment: Integral dx/(1+x)^2 = arc tan x

Comment: $\frac 1{1+x^2}\neq \frac 1{(1+x)^2}$

Answer (score 4):

Continuing from where you've left off:
$$\int \frac{dx}{(1+x)^2}=\int \frac{dy}{(1+y)^2}$$

---

Note that you have made a mistake in the integration of $\dfrac{1}{(1+x)^2}$. In fact:
$$\int \frac{dx}{\color{red}{1+x^2}}=\arctan {x}+C$$

---

One correct way to integrate it is via the substitution $u=1+x$, which gives $du=dx$:
$$\int \frac{dx}{(1+x)^2}=\int \frac{du}{u^2}=-\frac{1}{u}+C=-\frac{1}{x+1}+C$$
The same applies for the RHS.

Answer (score 2):

Separable ODE

$$(1+y)^2 = (1+x)^2 \frac{dy}{dx}$$

$$\int \frac{dy}{(1+y)^2}=\int \frac{dx}{(1+x)^2}$$

$$ \frac{1}{1+y}= \frac{1}{1+x}+c$$

Here I have taken advantage of both the left and middle term having a negative sign, and the constant on the right having unknown sign, so the negatives are consumed by $c$.

Rearrange to obtain answer.